# Post request from Angular app to Spring Boot API is failing

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement a simple frontend to my Spring Boot application. I have created a test frontend project using Angular, then generated a login component. I am trying to send POST request to my backend, but I always get the following error in my browser's console tab, even though I don't have any security on my backend API.

[image]

Here is my `login.components.ts` file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: './login.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent {
    name!: string;
    surname!: string;
    username!: string;
    password!: string;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    login() { }

    signUp() {
        const url = 'http://localhost:8080/users';
        console.log(this.name)
        console.log(this.surname)
        console.log(this.username)
        console.log(this.password)
        const data = {
            name: this.name,
            surname: this.surname,
            username: this.username,
            password: this.password
        };

        const headers = new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' 
        })

        this.http.post(url, data, { headers }).subscribe(
            (response) => {
                console.log(response);
            },
            (error) => {
                console.error(error);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

When I tried to send the same request to the backend API, the API worked perfectly. How can I send a POST request to my API correctly?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't have more code in the app. I think `login.components.ts` is the relevant code. As I have seen other posts, they sent their POST request as I do but I don't know what I am missing

Comment: The code in the client is irrelevant (except that it's making a non-"simple" request from a client that enforces CORS), the problem is _in the server_. Again, research CORS; read e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks. I fixed that when I added `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200/")` annotation to my controller. You were right. I needed to change my Backend API configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @jonrsharpe, there was no connection to the Angular application. I had to configure my backend application by adding the `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200/")` annotation in my Controller class.